# Compile C++ project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse IDE for C++ developers from the page http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index.php. What is further required to be able to compile and run C++ projects in Eclipse? May be CDT? Where can I download it for Windows7 64 bit?

Comment: yeah, go for CDT. My personal favorite is Visual Studio (for C++), though.

Comment: bit old, but still valid: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-stlcdt/

Answer (score 0):

I think u need also stuff like http://www.mingw.org/ for compiling and make.
It uses the GNU c++ compiler that is also used by Linux and has all of its standard libraries.
Search for ecplise cdt mingw in google and u will find enough tutorials i think.